# How to parse this array

Tags: php

I want to parse this array:

```
[
'field__i_dont_need' => 'foo',
'another_field_i_dont_need' => 'bar',
'user_name_1' => 'John',
'user_email_1' => 'john@gmail.com',
'user_name_2' => 'Jane',
'user_email_2' => 'jane@gmail.com'
]
```

to

```
$users = [
   0 => [
    'name' => 'John',
    'email' => 'john@gmail.com'
   ],
   1 => [
    'name' => 'Jane',
    'email' => 'jane@gmail.com'
   ]
]
```

I think I might need some regex magic but im unsure.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a community focused on doing someone else's job. Your chance of getting help will increase if you add anything you've tried to solve your problem.

Comment: @Michal Thanks for the comment. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
$outarray = [];
foreach ( $inarray as $k => $v )
    if ( preg_match( "/^user_(name|email)_(\d+)$/", $k, $m ) )
        $outarray[ $m[2] ][ $m[1] ] = $v;
```

It would produce keys `1` and `2` in `$outarray` rather than `0` and `1` but a `$outarray = array_values( $outarray )` would fix that.

Comment: I've edited the question, the original array contains fields I dont need.

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
 $arr = ['user_name_1' => 'John','user_email_1' => 'john@gmail.com','user_name_2' => 'Jane','user_email_2' => 'jane@gmail.com']
 $new_arr = array_values($arr);

 $j=0;
 $final = array();
 for($i=0;$i<count($arr)/2;$i++) {
     $final[$i]['name'] = $new_arr[$j];
     $j++;

     $final[$i]['email'] = $new_arr[$j];
     $j++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the following. It will work for any number of fields even if they are in various places in your array.

```
$data = [
    'field__i_dont_need' => 'foo',
    'another_field_i_dont_need' => 'bar',
    'user_name_1' => 'John',
    'user_email_1' => 'john@gmail.com',
    'user_name_2' => 'Jane',
    'user_email_2' => 'jane@gmail.com'
];

$temp = array();
//Take only the fields you need and their transformed key names
$fields = array(
    'user_name_'=>'name', 
    'user_email_'=>'email'
    );
$i = 0;

foreach($data as $key => $value) { //For all initial data
    foreach($fields as $s_key => $s_value) { //For all your field names you want
        if (strpos($key, $s_key) !== false) { //If it is a field name you want
            $t = explode($s_key, $key); //Explode to take its values
            if (!empty($t[1])) {
                if (empty($temp[$i])) {
                    $temp[$i][$s_value] = $value;
                } else {
                    $temp[$i][$s_value] = $value;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($temp);
```

**Result:**

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'John' (length=4)
      'email' => string 'john@gmail.com' (length=14)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Jane' (length=4)
      'email' => string 'jane@gmail.com' (length=14)
```